# Making a complete Rhombus with javascript

Tags: javascript

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zerupo/3/edit)

Hi, I am trying to make a Rhombus with Javascript, although for some reason I only have one of the sides. My program basically starts to write out the * symbols that make the Rhombus right where the beginning of the page starts. It makes a sort of vertical triangle shape. I have have tried doubling the amount of *, I also tried adding another if statement that that was supposed to do "you must have a space certain number of spaces dependent on the line number" but that didn't work.

```js
function drawMyLine(lengthLine, color1, color2) {
  var endLine = "<p>";
  for (var i = 0; i <= lengthLine; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      endLine += "<span style='color:" + color1 + "';>*</span>";

    } else {
      endLine += "<span style='color:" + color2 + "';>*</span>";

    }
  }
  endLine += "</p>";
  console.log(endLine);
  return endLine;
}


document.getElementById('line1').innerHTML = drawMyLine(0, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line2').innerHTML = drawMyLine(1, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line3').innerHTML = drawMyLine(2, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line4').innerHTML = drawMyLine(3, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line5').innerHTML = drawMyLine(4, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line6').innerHTML = drawMyLine(5, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line7').innerHTML = drawMyLine(6, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line8').innerHTML = drawMyLine(7, 'red', 'blue');


document.getElementById('line9').innerHTML = drawMyLine(7, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line10').innerHTML = drawMyLine(6, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line11').innerHTML = drawMyLine(5, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line12').innerHTML = drawMyLine(4, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line13').innerHTML = drawMyLine(3, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line14').innerHTML = drawMyLine(2, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line15').innerHTML = drawMyLine(1, 'red', 'blue');
document.getElementById('line16').innerHTML = drawMyLine(0, 'red', 'blue');
```

```html
<div id="line1">
</div>

<div id="line2">
</div>

<div id="line3">
</div>

<div id="line4">
</div>

<div id="line5">
</div>

<div id="line6">
</div>

<div id="line7">
</div>

<div id="line8">
</div>

<div id="line9">
</div>

<div id="line10">
</div>

<div id="line11">
</div>

<div id="line12">
</div>

<div id="line13">
</div>

<div id="line14">
</div>

<div id="line15">
</div>

<div id="line16">
</div>
```

Comment: [Try `*{text-align: center}`](http://jsbin.com/foxoqutedu/1/)

Comment: Use **for loops** !!! http://jsfiddle.net/sdxfu5Ls/